# Making a stopwatch counter with user filled data and with PAUSE/RESUME and RESET functionality

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, timer, stopwatch

Two input field "minute" and "second" is given. The value of the "second" field can exceed 60. A stopwatch needs to be created starting from the above timings.

Eg. If the minute is 5 and the second is 30. The stopwatch will start from 5:30 and then it will go on until both minute and second become 0.

Eg. If the minute is 5 and the second is 90. The stopwatch will start from 6:30 and then it will go on until both minute and second become 0.

There will be three-button with the "RESET", "PAUSE/RESUME" and "START" buttons.

RESET will reset the stopwatch to the user-given field.
PAUSE will pause the stopwatch and if clicked again it will resume it.
START will start the stopwatch at the initial go.

I am finding it difficult to create such a timer. Please help.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [min, setMin] = useState(0);
  const [sec, setSec] = useState(0);
  const [pause, setPause] = useState(true);

  const totalSeconds = min * 60 + sec;

  function startTimer(duration, display) {
    if (pause === true) {
      var timer = duration,
        minutes,
        seconds;
      const interval = setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
        console.log(minutes + ":" + seconds);
        setMin(minutes);
        setSec(seconds);

        timer = timer - 1;
        if (timer < 0) {
          clearInterval(interval);
        }
      }, 1000);
    }
  }
  function pauseToggle() {
    setPause(!pause);
    console.log(pause);
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <div>
        <input
          type="number"
          value={min}
          onChange={(e) => setMin(e.target.value)}
        />
        <input
          type="number"
          value={sec}
          onChange={(e) => setSec(e.target.value)}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            startTimer(totalSeconds);
          }}
        >
          START
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            pauseToggle();
          }}
        >
          PAUSE/RESUME
        </button>
        <button>RESET</button>
      </div>
      {min}:{sec}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please show the code you have so far and describe what isn't working see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with putting the code into your question. Otherwise this looks like an attempt to get someone else to do your homework. SO is willing to help when you are stuck but not do the whole thing for you.

Comment: @AHaworth Please look I have added the code. My pause and play functionality is not working

Answer (score 0):

To Start timer you can follow the steps mentioned below. It will help you.

Step 1: Minutes = 5 and Seconds = 90

Step 2: Convert all total minutes and seconds into total seconds

```
const min = 5;
const seconds = 90;
const totalSeconds = (min * 60) + seconds;
```

Step 3: Create the method that runs the timer.

```
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    const interval = setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;    
        console.log(minutes + ":" + seconds);

        timer = timer - 1;  
        if (timer < 0) {
           clearInterval(interval);
        } 
    }, 1000);
}
```

Step 4: Call this method on Start-Timer button click

Comment: How to display data from this function to the site and what to do if to pause and reset